# Whitespace on top of website

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I have a whitespace on top of my website that i want to remove and dont know how:

```css
body {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 900px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #5132FF;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  border: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>DevDoWeb.com</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="=width=1920, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleSheet.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <h3 class="headerText">Test</h3>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The dev tools tell me that it cant be maring, padding, or border.... i am really clueless on what to do here, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

In this case the white space is caused by the margin added from the browser stylesheet to `h3`. If you remove that by giving `h3` a margin of 0, you get rid of the white space.

```css
body {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 900px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #5132FF;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  border: 0;
  top: 0;
}

h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>DevDoWeb.com</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="=width=1920, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleSheet.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h3 class="headerText">Test</h3>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I just found out exactly that using the dev tools....i very much did NOT see the margin of the text itself :) Thanks, though.

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
h3 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```css
body {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 900px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #5132FF;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  border: 0;
  top: 0;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h3 class="headerText">Test</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS, make these changes

```
body {
border: 0;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

.header {
width: 900px;
height: 100px;
background-color: #5132FF;
text-align: center;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: -20px;
border: 0;
top: 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `margin-top` from the `headerText`

```css
body {
border: 0;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

.header {
width: 900px;
height: 100px;
background-color: #5132FF;
text-align: center;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 0;
border: 0;
top: 0;

}
.headerText {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"><h3 class="headerText">Test</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this on top of your css file.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend using a reset style sheet, one like [Eric Meyers](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). This link also explains what they are and why you should use them.

Comment: I will look into this. Thanks.